# DynamoDB difference in RCU's consumed while querying with and without filterExpressions

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi i've a dynamoDB table with around 632 items in a partition, each items is less than 4KB with average size around 250 bytes. each item has an attribute isActive which is boolean. i'm trying to fetch all the items who's isActive is true. currently there are around 6 items out of 632 which is active and rest of them are not active.
i was trying to query and in the query i was passing the partition key and a filterExpression where isActive is true, i was using the dynamo GUI to see different RCU consumed.

first i tried to fetch all the items in the partition, without any filterExpression and in the GUI it says it consumed 1.5 RCU's to fetch all the 632 items
[image]

then i added a filter expression to fetch only items whose isActive value is true, it returned 4 items but the consumed RCU's shows as 29.5
[image]

then i tried the same but with isActive set to false, it returned 628 items  with consumed RCU as 1.5[image]

My understanding with filtering with PK is that RCU won't change as dynamo first fetch all the items first and then apply the filters so the RCU won't change, but this says it's otherwise. can anyone help me how this RCU calculation's are done and what would be the best way to fetch all the active items without consuming that much RCU's

I used with dynamo GUI, tried to fetch with different filters and looked at the RCU's consumed

Comment: I think your understanding is correct, and the request should have used the same RCU with and without the filter. Moreover, an eventually-consistent scan that really returned 628 items of average size 0.25K should have used **at least** 628/4/4/2 = 19.6 RCUs, there is no way it could take just 1.5, that number just doesn't make sense. So I think the 1.5 number is an error, but don't know how it happened.

Comment: Partitions are internal concepts of Dynamodb. How do you know how many items you have per partition? Do you mean there are 632 items with the same `partitionId`?